# Show Category Results in another Column

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-list, lookup-column, calculated-column

Scenario - I have a custom list with columns.  One of the columns is titled Category as a drop down that lists 3 choices Bike, Car, Tractor.  Each category choice has another list of items.

**Choice 1: Bike**
 Peddles

Bell

Horn

**Choice 2: Car**

Automatic Windows

Alarm

Leather Seats

**Choice 3: Tractor**

Big Tires

Horn

Big Seat

The idea is if I click any of the categories the 3 selections connected to the category would show in the next column as a drop down.  Look at the picture. Here is what I am trying to do... I picked Bike the 3 selections appear in the next column as a drop down.

Question - How would I do this in SharePoint?  Could I use lookup columns with calculated columns?

[image]

Comment: This is a typical application for (SP2013) CSR - Client Side Rendering JavaScript.. requires moderate to senior level JavaScript experience.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Is this only way? Can I use a workflow instead? Thanks

Comment: No, because a workflow has nothing to do with your screen; will run in the background (sometimes taking minutes) This is Front End User Experience you want to build, so requires the language spoken by the Browser... JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible from any OOTB SharePoint feature. You either need to use InfoPath to set up the cascading drop down or create a custom form and use jQuery/JavaScript/Client or Server object model to do it.